# Excel Rounding nested if statement

Tags: excel, if-statement

I am trying to write a rounding if statement. If cell <50 round to the nearest 5, if cell is >50 but <1000 round to the nearest 10, if cell is >1000 round to the nearest 100. Can anybody help me out?

My attempt

```
=IF((T2<50, ROUND(T2*2,-1)/2),IF(AND(T2>50,T2<1000,ROUND(T2,-1)),ROUND(T2,-2)))
```

I was able to write a similar statement (If cell >0 but <1000 round to nearest 10, otherwise round to nearest 50)

```
=IF(AND(S3>0,S3<1000),(ROUND((S3),-1)),(ROUND((S3)*2,-2)/2))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
=IF(A1<50,MROUND(A1,5), IF(AND(A1>=50,A1<1000),MROUND(A1,10),MROUND(A1, 100)))
```

The MROUND operator (documentation [here](https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2015/08/06/excel-round-functions/#CEILING-function)) rounds to the nearest multiple, which I think is what you're looking for. You also have some issues with your paren grouping, but excel doesn't make it easy to chain `if` statements.  Your `AND` statement needs to wrap just just the two evaluations and return `MROUND(<cell>, 10)` when true.

Comment: I understand. Thank you very much dblackhorse, I believe all is well now! You rock!

Answer (score 0):

Did you just get a bit mixed up with the IF syntax?

```
=IF(T2<50, ROUND(T2*2,-1)/2,IF(AND(T2>50,T2<1000),ROUND(T2,-1),ROUND(T2,-2)))
```

The general form is

```
IF (logical test, result if true, result if false)
```

You also had some unnecessary brackets and didn't close the AND brackets.

Comment: Yes you are correct, I had exceeded my frustration limit with Excel and wanted to consult the experts